# SQL replace list of strings with element prefixes

Tags: sql, postgresql

in Postgres, I have a table with a column which is a list of text:

```
devdb=> \d txyz
               Table "public.txyz"
    Column     |  Type  | Collation | Nullable | Default
---------------+--------+-----------+----------+---------
 status        | text   |           |          |
 lstcol        | text[] |           |          |
```

and `lstcol` contains

```
devdb=> select lstcol from txyz limit 1 ;
                                 lstcol
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"ABCD - Company One Ltd","EFG - Second Corp."}
```

I want to replace each element contained in the list with the word that precedes the `" - "`, obtaining

```
 {"ABCD","EFG"}
```

How can I achieve that?
It is fine to create another column, and then replace the original one.

My SQL isn't stellar and this project has a lot of it. Any help is deeply appreciated.
Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the existing table (i.e. transform the existing column contents) like this:

```sql
update txyz 
 set lstcol = (select array_agg(trim(split_part(s, '-', 1))) from unnest(lstcol) s);
```

And it would be good to `vacuum` table txyz after that.

Comment: Thank you. Now it has `{"DBAG ","FRAZ "}`. How do I get rid of the trailing space i each element?

Comment: Use `trim`. I have edited my answer again. Big mistake in the office hurry ...

Comment: I have screwed up my table already trying to fix it myself. But thank you for the answer

Answer (score 1):

One method is a lateral join which pulls the array apart, picks out the the piece you want, and then reaggregates:

```
select t.*, x.ar
from txyz t cross join lateral
     (select array_agg(split_part(col, ' - ', 1)) as ar
      from unnest(t.lstcol) col
     ) x;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=53293804fe6dde5f34684241a0fd50b0) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I am trying to stay away from complicated queries in the code when it runs. I want to transform the present column contents to the new format once only, so I can later use a simple `select.. where val=ANY(lstcol)`

Comment: @Pynchia . . . I don't know what you mean by "complicated query".  This is pretty simple and can easily be incorporated into a `where` clause.

Comment: "..when it runs.". Read my comment again please. I want a simple and light query to apply to a transformed table

Answer (score 0):

You should to read official docs of Postgres on it's official site.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/arrays.html  - this part of Manual describes arrays and operation with ones.

Comment: Why didn't I think of that! Please I would have not asked a question